# Why char is of 1 byte in C language

Tags: c, char, language-lawyer

Why is a `char` `1` byte long in C? Why is it not `2` bytes or `4` bytes long?

What is the basic logic behind it to keep it as `1` byte? I know in Java a `char` is `2` bytes long. Same question for it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`char` is 1 byte in `C` because it is specified so in standards.

The most probable logic is. the (binary) representation of a `char` (in standard character set) can fit into `1` byte. At the time of the primary development of `C`,  the most commonly available standards were `ASCII` and `EBCDIC` which needed 7 and 8 bit encoding, respectively. So, `1` byte *was* sufficient to represent the whole character set.

OTOH, during the time `Java` came into picture, the concepts of extended charcater sets and `unicode` were present. So, to be *future-proof* and support extensibility, `char` was given `2 bytes`, which is capable of handling *extended* character set values.

Comment: Of course, even there they screwed up… a 16-bit `char` isn't capable of representing every Unicode character.

Comment: @duskwuff: Not only that, but while the intention may have been to avoid being English-centric, in many usage cases UTF-16 will end up being bulkier than UTF-8 even for languages which use many characters that would be represented more compactly in UTF-16, because much of the text that machines process is designed to be machine-readable rather than human-readable, and machine-readable text is usually ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

Why would a `char` hold more than 1byte? A char normally represents an ASCII character. Just have a look at an ASCII table, there are only 256 characters in the (extended) ASCII Code. So you need only to represent numbers from 0 to 255, which comes down to 8bit = 1byte.

Have a look at an ASCII Table, e.g. here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Thats for C. When Java was designed they anticipated that in the future it would be enough for any character (also Unicode) to be held in 16bits = 2bytes.

Answer (score 5):

It is because the C languange is 37 years old and there was no need to have more bytes for 1 char, as only 128 ASCII characters were used (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

When C was developed (the first book on it was published by its developers in 1972), the two primary character encoding standards were ASCII and EBCDIC, which were 7 and 8 bit encodings for characters, respectively.  And memory and disk space were both of greater concerns at the time; C was popularized on machines with a 16-bit address space, and using more than a byte for strings would have been considered wasteful.

By the time Java came along (mid 1990s), some with vision were able to perceive that a language could make use of an international stnadard for character encoding, and so Unicode was chosen for its definition.  Memory and disk space were less of a problem by then.

Answer (score 2):

The C language standard defines a virtual machine where all objects occupy an integral number of abstract *storage units* made up of some fixed number of bits (specified by the `CHAR_BIT` macro in limits.h).  Each storage unit must be uniquely addressable.  A storage unit is defined as the amount of storage occupied by a single character from the basic character set<sup>1</sup>.  Thus, *by definition*, the size of the `char` type is 1.

Eventually, these abstract storage units have to be mapped onto physical hardware.  Most common architectures use individually addressable 8-bit bytes, so `char` objects usually map to a single 8-bit byte.

Usually.

Historically, native byte sizes have been anywhere from 6 to 9 bits wide.  In C, the `char` type must be *at least* 8 bits wide in order to represent all the characters in the basic character set, so to support a machine with 6-bit bytes, a compiler may have to map a `char` object onto two native machine bytes, with `CHAR_BIT` being 12.  `sizeof (char)` is still 1, so types with size `N` will map to `2 * N` native bytes.

---

<sup>1.  The basic character set consists of all 26 English letters in both upper- and lowercase, 10 digits, punctuation and other graphic characters, and control characters such as newlines, tabs, form feeds, etc., all of which fit comfortably into 8 bits.</sup>

Comment: The basic character set on an ASCII system could easily fit in seven bits; I suspect `char` is required to be at least eight because when C was invented octets were starting to emerge as a common standard, nobody used seven-bit storage units, and bending over backward to support a vaguely-imaginable machine with seven-bit addressable storage units didn't seem worthwhile.

Comment: You are correct; the basic character set fits into 7 bits (hence why it fits comfortably into 8).  The 8th bit was originally used as a parity bit for error checking (both over comm lines and in memory).  Nevertheless, the C standard mandates that `char` types occupy *at least* 8 bits, regardless of how many bits it takes to represent those basic characters.

Comment: I wonder whether 8 bits were used rather than 7 to allow parity checking, or if 8 were used because it was easier to have an even number, and parity checking was added as a "we've got this bit and we may as well try to do something with it"?  An octet can conveniently store two base-16 or base-10 values, or four base-4 values; a sextet could conveniently hold two base-8 or three base-4 values.  A septet could kinda-sorta hold two base-10 values or base-11 values, but not nearly as conveniently as an octet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than a byte to represent the whole ascii table (128 characters).

But there are other C types which have more room to contain data, like **int** type (4 bytes) or **long double** type (12 bytes).

All of these contain numerical values (even chars! even if they're represented as "letters", they're "numbers", you can compare it, add it...).

These are just different standard sizes, like cm and m for lenght, .